# Is it possible in asp.net server code to display the controls as they are built?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using C#, I have a web page that is building 5 graphs & 5 tables in the code behind.  It takes about 20-30 seconds for all these to get built, and then they all just display onto the page at once.  Before they display, the page does not load at all and there is no indication that anything is happening (i.e. the mouse changing, the page loading into a "blank" state).  I do understand that is the nature of server-side processing, but I was hoping there were some tricks I don't know about, that will start to display each table or graph immediately after it's built?  Could I build each control via User Control? Could update panels help in some way? Building User Controls into Update Panels?  Is there a way I can at least get the page to load and display a progress bar while the initial load is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is break your graphs and tables up into individual pages and then your main page is a series of iframes, each of which loads from one of those individual pages. Then, they'd all get kicked off nearly the same time and as individual graphs/tables completed they'd display without having to wait for the rest.

Might be a good way to separate concerns a bit as well - several pages each responsible for a single graph/report as opposed to a single page that does them all.

Comment: I have never used iframes before, but i just read up on them and they sound perfect...can't wait to give them a try...thanks for the quick response!!